# Python script to download jpg from an increasing number in url

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to download JPG files from a url.

https://example.com/ebooks/47820eb8e1eda4a69aba442a/images/1.jpg

The book has 641 pages and I don't want to download it manually.
The site doesn't require special cookies to access thhe image
I tried to create a script to save it to a directory but it did not work.

```
import urllib.request
import os
os.chdir("E:\Downloads") #your path
i=1;
while i<615:
try:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://example.com/ebooks/47820eb8e1eda4a69aba442a/images/"+ str(i)+".jpg")
i+=1;
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Is your code formatted properly? The `try` after `while` doesn't seem properly indented.

Comment: `python 2` or `python 3`? you tagged them both

Comment: You're halfway there. Just a) learn how `try/except` clauses work; b) use the data returned by `urlretrieve`; c) learn how to save the latter to a file; and d) ident your code properly (this should probably be the first thing to do).

Comment: This is my first time coding in python, actually I accept any suggestion that can get the job done, python is just the first thing crossed my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't care about Python in particular, you can use `curl` in a batch file

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a "x = 1"
:while1
    if %x% leq 615 (
        curl --insecure --silent https://example.com/ebooks/47822eb8e1eda4a69aba442a/images/%x%.jpg -o E:\downloads\%x%.jpg
        set /a "x = x + 1"
        goto :while1
    )
endlocal
```

The curl  lines look like

```
curl --insecure --silent https://example.com/ebooks/47820eb8e1eda4a69aba442a/images/1.jpg -o E:\downloads\1.jpg
curl --insecure --silent https://example.com/ebooks/47820eb8e1eda4a69aba442a/images/2.jpg -o E:\downloads\2.jpg
curl --insecure --silent https://example.com/ebooks/47820eb8e1eda4a69aba442a/images/3.jpg -o E:\downloads\3.jpg
```

Comment: Is there any way i can create the url without typing it myself?

Comment: @Tom if you look at the script you only type it once and the script generates 615 urls

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
import os
path = "E:\\Downloads\\" #your path
i=1
while i<615:
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://example.com/ebooks/47820eb8e1eda4a69aba442a/images/"+ str(i) +".jpg", path+ str(i) +".jpg")
    except Exception:
        pass
    i+=1
```

Try this.
Also, your question is tagged with python2.7 even though your code is in python 3 (urllib.request doesn't exist in 2.7)

Comment: I tried in both linux and windows, nothing downloaded. I am running python 3.